# Different behavior when nesting Transform.scale and Transform.translate

Tags: flutter

I want to implement scale and translate behavior. I write it in _TransformScaleAndTranslate().

But I got different behavior between 
[Transform.translate outside Transform.rotate]
vs 
[Transform.rotate outside Transform.translate]

The result shows that if I translate after scale, [Transform.translate outside Transform.rotate] can't translate follow my pointer correctly.

Is there something wrong? or anything I didn't get it?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test1'),
      ),
      body: const _BodyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class _BodyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const _BodyWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  __BodyWidgetState createState() => __BodyWidgetState();
}

class __BodyWidgetState extends State<_BodyWidget> {
  Offset _startFocalPoint = Offset.zero;
  Offset _lastOffset = Offset.zero;
  Offset _currentOffset = Offset.zero;
  double _lastScale = 1.0;
  double _currentScale = 1.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onScaleStart: _onScaleStart,
      onScaleUpdate: _onScaleUpdate,
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          _TransformScaleAndTranslate(_currentOffset, _currentScale),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onScaleStart(ScaleStartDetails details) {
    _startFocalPoint = details.focalPoint;
    _lastOffset = _currentOffset;
    _lastScale = _currentScale;
  }

  void _onScaleUpdate(ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
    if (details.scale != 1.0) {
      double currentScale = _lastScale * details.scale;
      if (currentScale < 0.5) {
        currentScale = 0.5;
      }

      setState(() {
        _currentScale = currentScale;
      });

    // The place I calculate for translate
    } else if (details.scale == 1.0) {
      Offset currentOffset =
          _lastOffset + (details.focalPoint - _startFocalPoint) / _lastScale;

      setState(() {
        _currentOffset = currentOffset;
      });
    }
  }
}

class _TransformScaleAndTranslate extends StatelessWidget {
  final Offset _currentOffset;
  final double _currentScale;

  const _TransformScaleAndTranslate(
    this._currentOffset,
    this._currentScale, {
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  //Put Transform.translate or Transform.scale outside got different behavior when translate after scaled.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.translate(
      offset: _currentOffset,
      child: Transform.scale(
        scale: _currentScale,
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/elephant.jpg',
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/lib/matrix_gesture_detector.dart

Comment: Thank you for telling me there's another option to do it quickly, I'll try to understand matrix_gesture_detector, but I still want to know what's the difference between these two.

Comment: so you have to get some [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) skills as [Transform.scale](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e10df3c1a6/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart#L1197) and [Transform.translate](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e10df3c1a6/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart#L1158) use matrix under the hood